# Preencher ArrayList dinamicamente ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: firebase, arraylist, dinâmico

a tela principal do meu app é composta por algumas sessões usando o RecyclerView.
Para o adapter do meu recyclerview eu passo uma arraylist do tipo Sessoes para que a tela fique da maneira como quero. Porém essa arraylist eu só consigo preencher estaticamente. Eu gostaria de preenchê-la dinamicamente apenas acrescentando um campo no firebase, para que eu não precise mexer no código cada vez que eu queira adicionar ou excluir uma sessão. Abaixo seguem a tela e os códigos. Eu utilizo o firebase como backend.

Classe Sessões:

```
public class Sessoes {
private String nomeSessao;
private String descricaoSessao;
private String nomeSessaoBD;
private String img;

public Sessoes (){

}

public Sessoes(String nome, String desc, String nomeBD){
    nomeSessao = nome;
    descricaoSessao = desc;
    nomeSessaoBD = nomeBD;
}

public String getNomeSessao() {
    return nomeSessao;
}

public void setNomeSessao(String nomeSessao) {
    this.nomeSessao = nomeSessao;
}

public String getDescricaoSessao() {
    return descricaoSessao;
}

public void setDescricaoSessao(String descricaoSessao) {
    this.descricaoSessao = descricaoSessao;
}

public String getNomeSessaoBD() {
    return nomeSessaoBD;
}

public void setNomeSessaoBD(String nomeSessaoBD) {
    this.nomeSessaoBD = nomeSessaoBD;
}

public String getImg() {
    return img;
}

public void setImg(String img) {
    this.img = img;
    }
}
```

Código de preenchimento da arraylist:

```
public List<Sessoes> todasAsSessoes() {

    List<Sessoes> sessoes = new ArrayList<>();

    Sessoes sessoes_1 = new Sessoes("Próxima Ação","Informações sobre a próxima ação a ser realizada.", "proxima_acao" );
    Sessoes sessoes_2 = new Sessoes("Galeria", "Fotos das ações já realizadas.", "galeria");
    Sessoes sessoes_3 = new Sessoes("Quero Participar", "Quer ser voluntário em alguma ação?", "quero_participar");
    Sessoes sessoes_4 = new Sessoes("Quero Doar", "O que você quer doar?", "quero_doar");
    Sessoes sessoes_5 = new Sessoes("Calendário", "Confira o calendário das nossas ações.", "calendario");
    Sessoes sessoes_6 = new Sessoes("Locais atendidos", "Confira os locais já visitados pelo Doe Amor", "locais_atendidos");
    Sessoes sessoes_7 = new Sessoes("Contatos","Fale conosco!", "contatos");
    Sessoes sessoes_8 = new Sessoes("Redes Sociais", "Junte-se a nós e espalhe o amor pelas suas redes", "redes_sociais");

    Sessoes[] sessoesAdd = {sessoes_1, sessoes_2, sessoes_3, sessoes_4, sessoes_5, sessoes_6, sessoes_7, sessoes_8};

    for (int i=0 ; i <sessoesAdd.length ; i++){
        sessoes.add(sessoesAdd[i]);        }

    return sessoes;
}
```

É justamente esse código acima que eu preciso mudar para ser preenchido dinamicamente.

Código da passagem da arraylist para o adapter da recyclerview:

```
 sessoes = todasAsSessoes();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    AdapterSessoes adapter = new AdapterSessoes(sessoes, this);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
```

Tela de como ficam dispostas as sessões:

[image: Tela das sessões]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos lá...

A primeira coisa em mente é ter que carregar os dados do Firebase.

*Lembrando que essa não é a melhor forma de acessar sua base de dados. É apenas
a mais rápida do ponto de vista da implementação.*

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            ...
           ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
              @Override
              public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot) {
                       mListaSessoes.add(snapshot.getValue(Sessao.class));
                   }
                   mSessaoAdapter.setListaSessoes(mListaSessoes);           
              }
              @Override
              public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                  // Aconteceu algo de errado
              }
           };
           mFirebaseReference.child("sessoes")
                 .addValueEventListener(listener);
        }
    }
```

Então faça seu adapter inicializar a lista de sessões por um `setter`

```
public void setListaSessoes(@NonNull ArrayList<Sessao> listaSessoes) {
       this.sessoes = listaSessoes;
}
```

Comment: Cara, desculpe a ignorância mas é que sou iniciante. Eu já li a documentação do firebase e fiz uns testes de funcionamento. 
Porém aqui eu não consegui identificar como que eu irei preencher os dados no objeto. Tenho 4 atributos nele que são. Da maneira como colocou se entendi bem, ele já carregará os 4 valores do firebase no objeto, mas como ele saberá em qual atributo colocar?

Comment: Desculpa a demora em responder. Enfim, não sei se você já resolveu seu problema, mas vamos lá respondendo sua dúvida: quando você chama `getValue(Sessao.class)`, o método já mapeia as propriedades quem vêm da base de dados com base nos nomes dos getters e setters do seu modelo (Sessao.class).  Por exemplo: se  eu tenho um `getName()`, `getNumber()` e `getAddress()` ele já mapeia as propriedades na base de dados como `name`, `number`, `address`; e quando você recupera os dados passando seu modelo, ele já sabe onde setar o valores: `setName()`, `setNumber()` e `setAddress()`

Comment: Então os nomes na base de dados tem que ser os mesmos que estão na minha classe?

Comment: Isso mesmo @MarceloPortela. Ainda continua com dúvida?

Comment: Manoooo VALEU DEMAIS, consegui resolver aqui.... Obrigado Ivan Silva

Comment: Fico feliz em ajudar @MarceloPortela! Se seu problema foi resolvido graças à minha resposta, por favor, aceite-a como correta.